# Why it is discouraged to use autoRequery in CursorAdapter?

Tags: android

There is a [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#CursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor,%20boolean%29) for the `CursorAdapter` which has an interesting flag - `autoRequery`.

It is stated:

> If true the adapter will call requery() on the cursor whenever it
>   changes so the most recent data is always displayed. Using true here
>   is **discouraged**.

What's the point to create the feature which is discouraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Docs it is discouraged because it results in `Cursor` operations to be performed on the application's UI thread

Because of this it causes Performance Issue for the App

Well To add more ...Other Solution for This is Using `swapCursor()`

**Solution:**

```
CursorDemo cursorDemo = new CursorDemo(PrintContent.this, cursor);

cursorDemo.swapCursor(cursor_update);
```